# Making button in JList clickable

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlist

I can't believe this does not work.

I have a JList. I have set its renderer as follows. Basically `RankingPanel` is a JPanel with two labels and a button.

```
topAchieverList = new JList();
topAchieverList.setCellRenderer(new TopBottomCellRenderer());
```

Here is my TopBottomCellRenderer.

```
class TopBottomCellRenderer extends RankingPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    public TopBottomCellRenderer() {
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        try {
            Achievers achiever = (Achievers) value;

            if (achiever == null) {
                return this;
            }
            itemRank.setText("#" + achiever.rank);
            itemUnits.setText("" + achiever.units);

            //this is the button that does not click
            itemNameButton.setText(achiever.name);

            //set bg
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            return this;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

The list renders properly but the `JButton` is not clickable. Clicking it does nothing.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renderers are just "rubber stamps" painted onto the component. They are not live, interactive components.

See this answer: [JButton in JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447972/jbutton-in-jlist-cell-is-not-clickable/13458447#13458447) for one possible solution.  Effectively, you add a `MouseListener` to your `JList`, determine which particular button is being rendered at that click-point, then programmatically click that button.

Or, you could make a `JPanel` of buttons, and place the panel in a `JScrollPane`.

Or, you could make a single-column `JTable`, where you could implement a custom TableCellEditor, as seen here: [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Comment: So basically its not possible. There are "hackish" ways to force it to happen... I ended up adding all my `RankingPanel` objects to a `JPanel` which i added to a `JScrollPane'. Thanks for the help.